# The browser doesn't close when test fails

Tags: selenium, grid

I'm using the selenium grid 2 for parallel testing. I have next problem, when an test is fail, the browser isn't closed that cause block the node. If possible to define any timeout for the node to restart the browser or canceling test?

Comment: What language are you using for your tests? What does your test code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch and to close browser if test fail use finally

```
try{
steps you want to test
}
catch(exception e){
System.out.println(e.printstacktrace)
}
finally{
driver.close();
driver.quit();
}
```

at any cost finally block will execute and your browser will close.

Answer (score 0):

If the test fails on a selenium grid2 Node, the node is not blocked. The same node can be used for another test even if the browser is left open from the previous failed test.